# Failed getting devices issue in Appium

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium-ios

Appium version :1.5.3
Xcode : 7.3.1

When clicking the inspector following issue is displaying.

error: Failed getting devices. Err: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments' -s devices ia null.

Please Help me here it's a blocker. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did your device connected properly? Can you tell are you trying with real devices or emulators.

Comment: Hi Anuraj, i'm using Simulators,